# Plotly scatter plot animation with trailing lines/trace

Tags: python, plot, powerbi, plotly

I'm doing some z-score analysis per subject over time. So I've decided to use Plotly Scatter plot to do the job.

I would like to add a feature where as the animation plays out, a line is left behind for each scatter. I'm doing this over POWER BI.

This is the code I have so far.

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np 

dataset = pandas.DataFrame(Subject, Year, Z-Score)
dataset = dataset.drop_duplicates()
    
x= dataset["Year"] 
y= dataset["Z-Score"] 
    
plot = px.scatter(dataset,
                    x, y,hover_name="Subject", color="Subject",
                    animation_frame="Year", animation_group="Subject",
                    range_x=[2000,2025], range_y=[-3,3])

plot.update_traces(marker_size=10) # Set marker size
plot.update_layout(title='Z-Score Anlaysis per Subject') # Title 
#plot.show() # Show the visual
```

Desired results [image: This is what the end result should be]

Here is a sample data from excel.

> [image: Blockquote]

Thank you

Comment: Why is this tagged matplotlib if you want a solution for plotly?

Comment: can you add some sample data.  it's really not clear as x is year, y is z-score and animation_frame is year (same as x)  plus nothing for bubble size.  your sample code for creating a dataframe looks incorrect, it Subject, Year and Z-Score are lists/arrays.   I would expect it to be expressed as a dict

Comment: I uploaded the excel file. Its a simple data set.